# Linq: Limit how many items are taken in a list of objects that contain another list

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a list of themes, and each theme has a list of books. Themes and Books are their own table - so it's a many-to-many relationship.

When I get a list of the themes I'd like to limit the number of books that are retrieved.

The only way I've managed to do this is manually - get the list of themes, then in a for loop get the books and only take how ever many I want

```
foreach (var theme in filteredList)
{
    var bookQuery = _bookRepository.Query().AsNoTracking()
        .Where(b => b.Themes.Any(t =>t.Id == theme.Id))
        .Take(bookCount);
}
```

Theme Entity:

```
public class Theme : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public string Subtitle { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; private set; }
}
```

Book Entity

```
public class Book : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public string Summary { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? PublishDate { get; private set; }

    public decimal? Rating { get; private set; }

    [JsonIgnore, IgnoreDataMember]
    [ForeignKey("Publisher")]
    public Guid? PublisherId { get; private set; }
    public Publisher Publisher { get; private set; }

    [JsonIgnore, IgnoreDataMember]
    public ICollection<Theme> Themes { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `_bookRepository`? If you're using EF/EFCore then you should not be using the repository anti-pattern because your `DbContext` and `DbSet<T>` types _are_ your repository already.

Comment: `.AsNoTracking()` <-- Why are you using `AsNoTracking()`? Using it does _not_ significantly improve performance and it _breaks_ EF's ability to match subsequently-loaded related entities (either via `Include()` or via `Load()` calls). No-one should be using `AsNoTracking()` without actual profiler performance data to justify it, imo.

Comment: _"When I get a list of the themes I'd like to limit the number of books that are retrieved."_ - you can't use `.Take()` (which corresponds to `LIMIT` or `TOP` in SQL) without a meaningful `ORDER BY` predicate - otherwise you'll get arbitary rows returned (e.g. say you want the "top 100 rows"  returned - that's okay, but what criteria are you using to determine inclusion in the top 100 when you have 5 million source rows?)

Comment: `.Where(b.Themes.Any(t =>t.Id == theme.Id))` <-- This is not valid C# - you haven't defined/declared `b`. I think you mean `.Where( b => b.Themes.Any( theme => theme.Id == themeId  ) )` - but using `Any` inside `.Where` in Linq-to-Entities usually does not generate the best underlying SQL. Please edit your question to show us your full schema, including `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the feedback!

I'm using domain driven development - so the repository pattern is [the standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design).

As for the other comments - I've minimized the code as much as possible to leave out anything that isn't relevant to the question. Your comment on .Take() is valid, but not really relevant to the question.

You are right about the invalid c# code though - in minimizing the code I made an error. Will correct it now.

Comment: @Dai I added the relevant code so you can see that there is a many-to-many relationship between books and themes

Comment: You're misreading that Microsoft architecture article: it says right at the top: _"EF DbContext implements both the Repository and the Unit of Work patterns."_ which means that if you're using EF you don't need to reimplement it the way you're doing in your code right now. (Furthermore, Microsoft's guidance is not in any way "the standard", as if there _was_ any standard anyway).

Comment: `.AsNoTracking()` <-- Do you have a **good** reason for using `AsNoTracking()`? It's cargo-cult to use that method without _actual_ benchmark or profiling data that shows that DbContext's object-tracker is causing problems. You should prefer using tracking because without it `Include` and `Load` methods won't work as-expected, and object-identity will break if you have a `JOIN` with a mismatched multiplicity.

Comment: Hey @Dai - thanks for the response & feedback!

It feels like this discussion has gone a bit off topic. I'd just like to know if there is a way to limit how many items are retrieved for a collections inside another collection using linq. If I remove the AsNoTracking() will it be possible? If so, do you have a code sample?

Comment: I'm using it because it's a fairly complex query - I haven't benchmarked it though (that's a good idea). What I've posted is just the relevant part of the query for the question. Perhaps I should have removed `.AsNoTracking()` so there is no confusion.

Comment: Since the relationship is many to many, I assume it is possible for a single book to appear in more than one theme, in which case the number of books retrieved depends on whether the books show up in other themes.

Comment: Assuming you are using EF Core (you didn't say what EF or database), you should be using [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) instead of your own querying.

Comment: Hi @NetMage oh wow - thank you! That looks exactly like what I'm looking for!

Yes - a single book can appear in multiple themes. When we retrieve a list of themes, we want to only get x number of books.

I'm using EF Core 7 and azure SQL server.

Comment: @NetMage do you want to submit this as an answer?

Comment: You may do so if you like. It is okay to answer your own post.